# Status bar is hidden but the tint is still seen

Tags: java, android, statusbar, android-statusbar

I have an Android app which has a activity that plays a video. While usually some activities in my app have dynamic status bar color, I have hidden the status bar when the video activity is in landscape. But even if I hide the status bar by fullscreen, the tint for the status bar still remains. Please tell me how I can hide the status bar tint.

Code for setting the status bar color

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(((Activity) context));
                tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
                tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(false);
                tintManager.setTintColor(Color.parseColor("#" + dynamicColor));
                float f = Float.parseFloat(".7");
                tintManager.setTintAlpha(f);
            }
```

The code I use for removing the status bar color

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
                tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(false);
                tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(false);
                float f = Float.parseFloat("0");
                tintManager.setTintAlpha(f);
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
```

Now in the tint removing code, I have set the flag `setStatusBarEnabled` to `false`. Even `setStatusBarColor`  is `TRANSPARENT`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: As you can see, the status bar is hidden but the tint is seen]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in onCreate()

Kotlin:

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Java: ( not sure )

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

These flags get reset once you move to a different view or activity.

Comment: I have written this code  and it does get called but even then it does not work. I have managed to get a fullscreen and hide the status bar but the tint overlay just won't go away.

Comment: The setSystemUiVisibility() function only has an effect if the view you call it from is visible. Are you ensuring this?

Comment: I call it from onConfigurationChanged() when my activity goes to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already tried this but just in case:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comes from
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html